# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Return the ratio of good to bad instances for different subsets of the dataset:

```
y2 = len(df[(df[df['class'] == 'good']) & (df[df['age']<40])])
```

Comment: I believe you want `y2 = len(df[(df['class'] == 'good') & (df['age'] < 40)])` . Combine the boolean _indexes_ not _dataframes_ created by those indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much @Henry Ecker. Now I understand.